# Entity-based schema updating in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, symfony

I am currently trying to get used to the Laravel framework with Symfony experience. For now everything looks to be quite fine. However, there is one thing that I'm missing in Laravel or I just couldn't really find how to do it.

In Symfony, one has the option to create entities like the following:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;
}
```

After creating this file, one could simply run `php app/console schema:doctrine:update --force` to update for example a MySQL database.

Now I've read that Laravel is using Eloquent, models and migrations to update databases accordingly. However, I am wondering if there is a similar way to update my database as the method used in Symfony. So when I run a command it automatically updates my database based on the entities I've created.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for does not exist natively.

However, a great package exists to provide the `annotation mapping` that you're looking for. Of course, this is much more than that and actually gives you almost all of the crucial missing pieces.

[You can find the package here](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm)

[You can find the documentation here](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.2/orm/meta-data)

Here's an example using the Meta Mapping from Doctrine in Laravel:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is pretty much what I'm looking for. Is there a special command for Laravel to update the database accordingly?